# update Telerik RadGrid by outside controls using ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, telerik-grid

i want grid to be rebound without refreshing page when search button is fired 
i've used PostBackTrigger  but it isn't worked for me

here is some part of my code.aspx

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server" />

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch"/>
<asp:Button Text="Search" runat="server" ID="btnSearch" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="pnlUpdate">
<ContentTemplate>
  <rad:RadGrid id="RadGrid1" runat="server" EnableAJAX="True">
   <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
     <rad:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="CustomerID" DataField="CustomerID"
      UniqueName= "CustomerID"></rad:GridBoundColumn>
     <rad:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="ContactName" DataField="ContactName"
      UniqueName= "ContactName"></rad:GridBoundColumn>
    </Columns>
   </MasterTableView>
 </rad:RadGrid>
</ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearch" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

so is there any trick to solve this issue ??
thanks to all

Milan Mendpara

Comment: What are you doing in the Code-Behind file to bind the data? Why are you not using a AsyncPostBackTrigger if you are enabling Ajax?

Comment: thanks lloyd for your reply, 
i've also tried it with AsyncPostBackTrigger but its not working too ..

from the codebehind i enable paging and rebind the grid with new datasource .. in grid_NeedDataSource()

Comment: Post your code behind code, you need to the binding in the Button click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defind any Button 'Click' [EventHandlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx) for either the OnClick or OnCommand for the button. Be sure that you are not unconditionally binding your Data in the Page_Load or Page_Init Events, check to see if the page is not handling a postback.

```
<asp:Button Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" runat="server" ID="btnSearch" />

// Change <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearch" />
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearch" />

// Code Behind EventHandler
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Retrieve and Bind Search Data to RadGrid1
    // You must Bind or Rebind the Datasource to the RadGrid control using the Bind() or Rebind() methods.
 }


// Check Databind is conditional if required
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    If (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // Bind Data if required
    }    

}
```

Comment: sorry lloyd i've defined OnClick but here i forgot write during posting question ..

i've just rectify my error

Comment: Is the page doing a postback? What is the Event handler code in the code-behind file?

Comment: protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState["serVal"] = txtSearch.Text;
        grid.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
        grid.Rebind();
    }

protected void grid_NeedDataSource(object source, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
       if (ViewState["serVal"] == null)
                ViewState["serVal"] = "";

          TestGridDataContext context = new TestGridDataContext();
 List<Employee> resultData = context.Employees.Where(emp => emp.empName.Contains(ViewState["serVal"].ToString())).ToList();
     
       grid.DataSource = resultData;
    }

Comment: You are not Binding the data to the Grid you mist call RadGrid1.Bind() or RadGrid1.Rebind();

Comment: ok i'm writing it too 

protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { ViewState["serVal"] = txtSearch.Text; grid.CurrentPageIndex = 0; RadGrid1.Rebind(); }

but still same situation ..

Comment: You need clear and to reset the RadGrid DataSource property to the NEW Data source and then explicitily BIND it!

Comment: Is the Page posting Back? and is the event firing? Use the debugger "F5".